# Android - Find a string inside a file and if exists get the line with eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need help with this.

I have a `for` and it checks some strings `StringToFind` (sometimes are few or even none and sometimes could be hundred or so), and I need to find the string inside a file, and if exists, I need to take the whole line, I need to do thins in Android with Eclipse, for example:

**Sample file:**

```
Orange, cherry, coconut
Apple, banana, lemon
Lime, pear, grape
```

**What I need:**

`StringToFind = "Apple";`, I need to find `Apple` inside a file (read from storage), and if `Apple` exists, take the line whole into another string: `StringFound = "Apple, banana, lemon"`.

Can someone help me with that?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing this currently? What's your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private String getStringFromFile(String matching, File inFile) throws IOException {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
   String line;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       if (line.contains(matching)) {
           br.close();
           return line;
       }
   }
   br.close();
   return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the text file
File file = new File("yourFile");

String StringToFind = "Apple";

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.equals(StringToFind));
            //Your String matches
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
```